# Measuring a capacitively-coupled potentiometer

Tags: operational-amplifier, high-impedance

Note: this is in problem/solution format, in terms of what I have already thought of. I know I know little enough to be prone to XY problems, and as such if there's a subproblem / subsolution that doesn't make sense, please tell me as such.

Root problem: I have a potentiometer whose wiper is capacitively coupled, and I'd like to be able to read its relative position with a microprocessor. Ideally, fairly accurately. (Note that the microprocessor I've got only has an 8-bit ADC so I'll need a ADC (or better processor) *anyways*.)

(So, roughly speaking: equivalent circuit is a potentiometer with a capacitor connected to the wiper. I have access to both ends of the potentiometer and the other end of the capacitor, but not the internal node.)

- Subproblem: I do not know the exact resistance of the potentiometer.

  - Solution: use something that measures the ratio of the two capacitor-to-end resistances.
- Subproblem: Said capacitance is (very) low (~20pF?)

  - Solution: use a fairly high frequency and something with a high input impedance.

    - Problem: ensuring that inductive effects don't become significant.

Idea: Put a sine wave on one pin of the potentiometer, connect the other end to ground, and measure the amplitude of the sine wave at the wiper. (Effectively: use the potentiometer as a voltage divider). This requires a fairly high frequency to have an impedance low enough to work with, but that's doable.

- Problem: accuracy near extremes

  - Solution: don't drive pot with full range.
  - Solution: use better detector.
- Subproblem: how to measure the amplitude?

  - Solution: use an envelope detector.

    - Problem: Susceptible to noise.
    - Problem: Output ripple.
  - Solution: rectify input and use a current detector.

    - Problem: input impedance

      - Solution: use a voltage follower

        - Problem: finding a voltage follower that works in this application.
    - Problem: Output ripple
  - Solution: Analog-divide the potentiometer output by the original sine wave

    - Problem: accuracy
    - Problem: phase shift

Idea: use potentiometer as part of an oscillator and measure frequency.

- Problem: I do not know the exact resistance of the potentiometer
- Problem: sensitive to exact capacitance
- Problem: noise

So: does anyone have any suggestions on this front? Beyond "I'm crazy"?

Comment: Get a simulator and iron things out that way. LTSpice is free.

Comment: If you'd like to avoid an XY problem, share what you're trying to accomplish. The obvious suggestion is to not capacitively couple to your wiper.

Comment: "_I have access to both ends of the potentiometer ... I do not know the exact resistance of the potentiometer._" Why not?

Comment: is wiper burnt out?  send pulse or square wave with variable current (series R) until Vout=Vin/2

Comment: Give us a photo too.

Comment: Why not is I'm exploring. Suffice to say, I'm exploring alternative ways of measuring linear travel. A standard linear potentiometer is a) expensive at larger sizes, b) hard to get at larger sizes, c) adds friction, and d) burns out quickly. The "standard" solution is to just use stepper motors, but those have other problems. Hence, I'm exploring other solutions.

Comment: "Why not?" - because I'm prototyping, and as such there is a fair amount of variation between copies (and, I suspect, a fair amount of temperature dependence).

Comment: "Is wiper burnt out" - there is no wiper - it's air-gapped. Your idea of a square wave voltage divider is interesting - but then I've got the problem of "how do I make a variable-current square wave". I'd worry about ringing.

Comment: Re. photo: this is intended as, effectively, a feasibility analysis. I'm not going to build it unless there's some chance that it'll work.

Comment: "The obvious suggestion is to not capacitively couple to your wiper." If you have a suggestion as to how to feasibly make a potentiometer wiper that will survive effectively-constant sliding without changing parameters over time, won't add much friction, and is >25cm or so in length, I'd love to hear it.

Comment: You might want to look into the way that digital calipers work. They are capacitively based (no resistive element at all) and achieve resolution of 0.01mm with travel of hundreds of mm, albeit in an incremental measurement mode (absolute measurements require zeroing).

Comment: The usual way to get long life and low friction with high linearity is to overlay a conductive plastic element on top of a wirewound element. The latter provides the linearity and the former a long-life smooth contact surface. Common in servo pots and pots used for feedback in machinery such as molding machines. They are not particularly expensive for an industrial part.

Comment: I'll be the first to point out that what you're talking about is no a potentiometer

Comment: Read up and see if any of the capacitive touch screens ICs can do what you want.  Research capacitive liquid tilt angle sensors and see if they have solved your problem already.

Comment: If you are hoping to use your linear 'pot' as feedback on a XY stage you need to remember that any scale error you cannot remove will become an increasing problem as your axis gets longer.  What might work OK at 30mm might be a waste of time at 300mm travel.  Micro-stepping a stepper motor gives scary amount or resolution and even half stepping with a threaded rod is hard to beat.  Making cheap servo control has been designed to death in cheap consumer ink-jet printers with an optical encoder strip and a decent DC motor and tight timing belts.

Comment: @KalleMP - I shall do so, thanks. And I very much doubt I'll be able to get decent precision out of this, as you say. However, it may be able to be enough precision to be able to turn a cheap periodic-incremental measurement into an absolute one. Microstepping has its own problems (it's often decidedly non-linear, for one)

Comment: @TLW The non-linearity of micro stepping is only a significant problem if you want accuracy that you cannot get from your hardware by increasing your step resolution.  The error is only a periodic oscillating error that can be NO WORSE than the half stepping error.  Using a couple of incremental channels in a grey code may be an option.

Answer (score 2):

This is not impossible. Drive the element with a voltage (preferably a sine wave) and simply synchronously demodulate the wiper voltage after buffering it with an AC-coupled amplifier. Since you are driving with a fixed voltage the exact resistance of the element is not important.

You can test this out with a common laboratory lock-in amplifier without building anything. It's also vaguely similar to how LVDT signal conditioners work.

Your problems will arise from the stray capacitance which will cause nonlinearity and frequency sensitivity in the pickup voltage, which is partly why I suggest a sine wave excitation.

You might want to consider using an LVDT rather than the pseudo-pot, depending on the physical constraints.

Comment: Yes, good +1. Also old graphic tablets were capacitive or inductive and achieved 10 step/mm resolution and 1/2mm accuracy.